# Which book would you recommend to test predictive power of statistical models

Tags: references, prediction

The title says it all. I'm interested in getting a better understand how to test the predictive power of your statistical models. As an example: Assuming you want to model a certain relationship with regression and test how it behaves to predict future values how do you go about it in a sound statistical sense? How about for more complicated models, like in machine learning or time series analysis? Is there a book with the foundation of such question or at least covering certain parts of it.

Comment: Testing predictive power is rather specific and simple, so you do not need a whole book on that. You need a test sample on which you will evaluate any model built on a training+validation sample. It is important that the model is built without using any information form the test sample, otherwise your evaluation may not be accurate (may be too optimistic). That is all.

Comment: @RichardHardy so cross validation is form a statistical point of you enough? But if there are some nice papers / books still happy to get any references

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: @RichardHardy enough is maybe the wrong word. So let me try ro rephrase: I used cross validation but can we do something on top of that to get even a better estimate of the predictive power? IMHO, cross validation results can be difficult to be interpreted.

Comment: Where is the difficulty in interpretation? You get a point estimate, you can get a whole distribution, pretty simple and informative. Also, I would stick to "using a test sample" instead of "cross validation" as the latter is a much broader term.

Comment: This video covers a lot on this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85dtiMz9tSo&t=169s

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good things about ["The Essential Guide to Effect Sizes: Statistical Power, Meta-Analysis, and the Interpretation of Research Results"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521142466)

You get so see how effect size and power are related, a topic that is often seen less than it should be in intro stats books.